# mysql.sock missing

Tags: mysql, log

I started my MYSQL database this morning but failed. And I tried all means I can think of:

```
chown -R mysql.mysql /var/lib/mysql
chmod g+w /var/run/mysqld
chgrp mysql /var/run/mysqld
chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mysql/
service mysqld stop; mysqld_safe --user=mysql &
```

but the file is still not there (/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock).
I checked the file /var/log/mysqld.log, it says:

```
130827 07:49:25 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
130827  7:49:26  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
130827  7:49:26  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130827  7:49:26  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 44233
130827  7:49:26 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: unknown option '--qviheadfv<F4><F4>--bdcvadsfefa'
130827  7:49:26 [ERROR] Aborting

130827  7:49:26  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
130827  7:49:31  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 44233
130827  7:49:31 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

130827 07:49:31 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

I got totally lost. What is the option '--qviheadfv--bdcvadsfefa'? Any suggestion?

Comment: Sounds like potentially garbage in my.cnf or your initscript from improper use of a text editor... or corruption of one of those files on disk.  Check those?

Comment: Thanks a lot! as you said, I deleted one line below and it turned normal:
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
qviheadfv<F4><F4>--bdcvadsfefa

servaer_id=2 log-bin=mysql-bin master-host=***.***.**.*** master-user=root master-password=***** master-port=3306 master-connect-retry=10 replicate-do-db=abc replicate-ignore-db=mysql