# mysql.sock not found on CentOS 7 machine

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

I am getting the following error when I try to log into mysql from the CentOS 7 terminal of the machine where mysql is installed:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

**So where can I find `mysql.sock` and how can I resolve this error?**

Here are a number of things I have tried already:

1.) I tried `cd /var/lib/mysql` and `ls -al`, but the resulting list of files did not contain `mysql.sock`.

2.) When I saw that `systemctl status mysqld` showed that mysql was stopped, I also tried `systemctl start mysqld` but the terminal just gave an unresponsive cursor without a new prompt, as if it were held up waiting for something, but it remained in that limbo state indefinitely.

3.) So I opened another terminal window and ran `systemctl status mysqld`, only to see that mysqld was again started.  But the error persists.

4.) I tried `find / -name "mysql.sock"` but the response was `find: ‘/run/username/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied`.

5.) Then I read [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530215/mysql-problem-no-mysql-sock) and tried `mysqladmin | grep d.sock` but there were no results.

6.) I even resorted to `yum remove mysql` followed by `yum install mysql`, but then `mysql -u root` still gives the same original error at top of this posting.

7.) And then I read [this other posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748478/cannot-find-mysql-sock), but `mysqladmin variables` gives the same error that it cannot connect because the mysql.sock cannot be found.

8.) And I tried `ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock` but the same error persisted even though a link to mysql became visible when I tried `cd /var/lib/mysql/` and `ls -al`

9.) Since the problem may have to do with the fact that `systemctl start mysqld` gets hung up, I read [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310782/mysql-daemon-failed-to-start-centos-6) and tried `chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql` and `systemctl start mysqld` but the result is 'Failed to issue method call: Unit mysqld.service failed to load: No such file or directory.'

10.) I then read [this posting](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48777/mysql-sock-missing), which caused me to run `mysql --help | grep "Default options" -A 1`. The result printed the locations where `mysql` looks for `my.cnf`.  I thus checked every location, and there was no `my.cnf` file to be found. But I did find a `mysql.cnf.rpmsave`, so I tried `mv mysql.cnf mysql.cnf.rmpsave`.  This caused there to be a `my.cnf` in the expected directory, but `systemctl status mysqld` says that `mysqld` is not found.  I tried `yum install mysql` again, but it told me that `mysql` is already installed.  So I suspect that `my.cnf` is corrupted.  If so, how can I fix it?  [Here is the link](https://jumpshare.com/v/xImomZMASgLWPUZ4Ic70?b=rr8My67FzHTNqagmLbTg) to a copy of `my.cnf` on a file sharing site.

11.) I then tried RolandoMySQLDBA's suggestion and tried:

```
[root@localhost]# mysqladmin -h127.0.0.1 -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -uroot -p shutdown
Enter password: 
mysqladmin: connect to server at '127.0.0.1' failed
error: 'Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)'
Check that mysqld is running on 127.0.0.1 and that the port is 3306.
You can check this by doing 'telnet 127.0.0.1 3306'
[root@localhost etc]# telnet 127.0.0.1 3306
bash: telnet: command not found...
```

But you can see I was not able to connect.  So I took the following steps, which include more detail of a preceding step above:

```
[root@localhost etc]# systemctl status mysqld -l
mysqld.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Dec 15 15:38:17 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Dec 15 15:38:17 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
Dec 15 15:38:17 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mysqld.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 15 15:38:17 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping MySQL Community Server...
Dec 15 15:38:17 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community  Server...
Dec 15 15:38:17 localhost.localdomain mysqld_safe[12886]: 141215 15:38:17 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysqld.log'.
Dec 15 15:38:17 localhost.localdomain mysqld_safe[12886]: 141215 15:38:17 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
Dec 15 15:38:17 localhost.localdomain mysqld_safe[12886]: 141215 15:38:17 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
Dec 15 15:38:25 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping MySQL Community Server...
Dec 15 15:38:25 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
[root@localhost etc]# systemctl start mysqld
Failed to issue method call: Unit mysqld.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
[root@localhost etc]# yum install mysql
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: repos.lax.quadranet.com
 * epel: mirrors.kernel.org
 * extras: repos.lax.quadranet.com
 * updates: repos.lax.quadranet.com
Package mysql-community-client-5.6.22-2.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 2):

To find out path to a socket `mysqld` process has opened you can use `lsof`:

```
# lsof -U -c mysqld -a
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
mysqld  18149 mysql   16u  unix 0xffff880037a7a700      0t0 126146 /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Thank you.  `lsof -U -c mysqld -a` produces `lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/username/1000/gvfs Output information may be incomplete.` and nothing else.

Comment: do you run it as root?

Comment: yes. I ran it as root.

Comment: is mysqld running at all? try without -a flag, does `lsof -U -c mysqld` output anything?

Comment: I just ran `lsof -U -c mysqld` but `mysqld` was not among the results.  What should I try?

Comment: `systemctl status mysqld` says `mysqld` is not installed, but `yum install mysql` says `mysql` is already installed.  See #11 at the end of my OP.

Answer (score 0):

Open `vi /etc/my.cnf` and add string:

```
bind-address        = localhost
```

This [worked for user AnupRaj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11483419) on the related Stack Overflow Q & A [Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (38)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5376427)

Comment: This would be a much better answer if it explained why it solved the problem. Link-only answers are frowned on due to link rot.